# Stemming Pandas Dataframe 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stem

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer
porter_stemmer = PorterStemmer()

df = pd.read_csv("last1.csv",sep=',',header=0,encoding='utf-8')

df['rev'] = df['reviewContent'].apply(lambda x : filter(None,x.split(" ")))
```

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HLbd.png)

I am trying to stem my dataframe. While tokenizing I am getting this error for

```
df['rev'] = df['reviewContent'].apply(lambda x : filter(None,x.split(" ")))
```

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

While using Stemming I also get the float problem

```
df['reviewContent'] = df["reviewContent"].apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])
```

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

What can I do?

Comment: Where is your data? What is your expected output? Your code isn't enough to help.

Comment: This is a dataset for yelp fake review. I am trying to stem my whole dataset. Should I upload the dataset too??

Comment: How about the first 5 rows instead?

Comment: I edited the post and added a photo of the dataset. Is it enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When tokenising your data, you don't need the `apply` call. `str.split` should do just fine. Also, you can split on multiple whitespace, so you don't have to look for empty strings.

```
df['rev'] = df['reviewContent'].astype(str).str.split()
```

You can now run your stemmer as before:

```
df['rev'] = df['rev'].apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])
```

Comment: Sorry getting another error:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 79-80: ordinal not in range(128)

I havo to do the following things to overcome the error:
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

is it okay?

Comment: @AshfaqAliShafin Yeah, that's okay. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

We can also write it this way

```
df['rev'] = df['rev'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: stemmer.stem(x))
```